# ¿Como redimensionar una imagen en un JPanel?

Tags: java, netbeans, imagen

Buenos días amigos, es mi primera pregunta en esta web, quisiera que me ayuden un poco con este código...

Este es el código que estoy usando, me devuelve la imagen con las dimensiones iniciales del jpanel; lo que quiero es que al maximizar la ventana (al redimensionarse el panel), se redimensione la imagen obteniendo el nuevo tamaño del panel.

Gracias por su ayuda.

```
public Panel(JPanel jPanel){
    this.x = jPanel.getWidth();
    this.y= jPanel.getHeight();
    this.setSize(x, y);
}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconos/fondo.jpg"));
    g.drawImage(img.getImage(), 0, 0, x, y, null);
}
```

Comment: Deberías verificar si las variables **x** e **y** están cambiando su valor al momento de cambiar el tamaño de la ventana o si se mantienen en el mismo que declaras al principio, si se mantienen igual, **nunca** vas a ver cambios, pues el **Panel** que declaras, se mantiene igual

Comment: Las variables si cambian el valor al momento de cambiar el tamaño de la ventana, la duda es como puedo obtener los valores en ese evento.

Comment: ¿Y qué tal si en vez de usar las variables **x** e **y**, creas una variable de tipo JPanel y al momento de crear el constructor, haces la referencia a `this.jPanel = jPanel;`? De esa manera, cuando haces el método *drawImage()** utilizas las coordenadas **jPanel.x** y **jPanel.y**.  Ya que al momento de pasar por el constructor, las variables **x** e **y** obtienen el primer valor del jPanel, pero no los demás, ya que no vuelves a tomar la referencia, en cambio, si declaras de esa manera, puedes obtener los valores siempre que quieras.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar este codigo y luego convertirlo en ImageIcon

```
 public BufferedImage redimensionar_imagenes(InputStream imagen, int x, int y){
   BufferedImage bi=null;

    try {

        //se obtiene la imagen original
        BufferedImage decodificado = ImageIO.read(imagen);
        ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon(decodificado);


        //se crea la nueva imagen con las dimensiones de interes
        bi = new BufferedImage(x, y, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(pic.getImage().getScaledInstance(x, y, Image.SCALE_FAST),0,0, null);
        g2.dispose();

        imagen.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Procesamiento.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }




return bi;
}
```

Comment: Gracias Andy, me sirvió de mucho. Saludos,